# Create a rule if sender or any recipient's email matches a search

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Rather than specify lists of people, I want to create a mail rule which matches if the sender or any recipient's email address is `<something>@abc.xyz`.

I cannot see a way to do this in the Rule Wizard, is it possible?

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, in the outlook client, we need to create two rules for recipients and senders who meet this condition, but we can't include them in one rule. As MIG mentioned, we just need to add "abc.xyz" fill in “specific words” of "with specific words in the sender's address" and "with specific words in the recipient's address" when creating rules.

In addition, I dare to guess that if you just need to find out the email address from the sender or any recipient whose email address is @abc.xyz. It's suggested that you could try to directly create a search folder (right-click search folder > New search folder), which can meet both conditions.
[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need two rules: one if the the address is the sender and the other if it's in the recipient list.

On the web app both are in the `It was sent or received` category. I think the Outlook app will have the same option.

Answer (score 0):

Use *"With specific words in the sender's address"*, then use *@abc.xyz* (so no wildcards or other prefixes, just that) as the value.

[image: Outlook 365 rules]

And yeah, you'll need a separate rule for recipients (*"With specific words in the recipient's address"*).